# Magento 2.4.5: Show out of stock notification on configurable product swatch selection

Tags: configurable-product, magento2.4.5

I want to show out of stock message on configurable product swatch selection.

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use try this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62051772/magento-2-how-to-display-simple-product-stock-on-on-a-configurable-product

Alter the code to show out of stock message if quantity is zero.